# Hand analysis no limit

Tags: poker-strategy

1/2 no limit 6 handed

All players are deep

**Pre flop**

Hero UTG
Q♠J♠
opens for 5

CO 
calls

BTN 
raises to 15

SB 
fold

BB
calls

CO
calls

**Flop**

Pot 46

T♠7⋄5⋄

Hero opens for 20 and gets 2 callers

**Turn**

Pot 106
8♠

BB opens for 60

What should hero do?

Comment: some info is missing, could you please edit it to include the full action of every player in every round? 1) During preflop action, after the BTN raises to 15 and the BB calls, does the UTG-hero also call? and what about the CO? 2) During the flop action, who are the 2 callers? 3) also some basic info regarding the opponents (if any) ?

Comment: @koita_pisw_sou I forget who called.  For sure one was BB.   No information on players.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the involving players are the hero, the BB and the initial BTN raiser.

Regarding the BB: He cold-called the preflop 3bet, then check-called flop and donk betted on the the turn. Looks quite fishy, yet his betting against 2 players looks strong, unless he is super-aggressive. His range should usually include a couple of strong hands (2pairs,straights,sets) together with strong combos (flush+pair, flush+gutshot,top_pair+gutshot, etc.).

Regarding the BTN: After raising preflop he is rather passive in a draw-heavy board. Some (small) percent of the time could be hiding a monster like pocket-tens,but most of the times he is folding to further aggression, if he is a solid player.

Your strategy: Assuming you play deep (~200BBs=400$), you have a very well covered flush draw and nut-straight-draw, which in case you hit, you can go for a very big bet in the river (you need to also evaluate the implied odds, not only the direct pot-odds). Also, you have the position on the OP, so in case he was betting with a medium-strength hand like T9o and a scary hard hits on the river, you could easily bluff him off, using a decent bet. Bearing in mind all these factors I would at least call (most of the times) and in some cases (depending on the OP) I would even raise (for the same reasons).

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the lead on the flop, you have no idea where they stand, I prefer a check-call, on the turn you probably have about 25% equity at best but its likely BB will have some of your outs and he's leading against the 3bet, pretty sure its a fold in my opinion, but happy to here other peoples thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I will not accept my own answer but I cannot see continuing here.

Flush draw is tempting but 20% for making it.

I cannot put BB on a bluff.  He could be on 9J, 9T, TJ, AT, TT, 77.

Hero also had a straight draw for 12 outs.  On second thought I wish I had called.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is a call on the turn. the hero has a gutshot straight draw as well as a flush draw and 2 overcards. Overcards might not be good here but there is still a lot of equity in this hand.